# Delegates and Events with multiple classes

Tags: c#, events, delegates

This has taken me quite a few days to develop a demo of communicating between classes with delegates and events.  I would like to know if this is the best practices way of accomplishing this passing of data between classes or not. If there is a better method please let me know. Specifically, if something happens in a subclass how do you get it back to the main class.  This would be particularly useful when doing n-tier architecture by separating out the User Interface from the Business Logic Level, and the Data Access Level.

I have a form that has 3 text boxes: tb1, tb2, and tbAnswer.
I also have a button that says "Add" and it is just button1.

The main form is:

```
namespace DelegateTest
{
    public delegate void ShowMessage(object sender, Form1.AnswerEventArgs e);

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void a_OnShowMessage(object sender, AnswerEventArgs e)
        {
            tbAnswer.Text = e.answer;
        }

        public class AnswerEventArgs :EventArgs
        {
            public string answer { get; set; }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddClass a = new AddClass();
            a.OnShowMessage += new ShowMessage(a_OnShowMessage);
            a.AddMe(Convert.ToInt16(tb1.Text), Convert.ToInt16(tb2.Text));
        }
    }
}
```

and the subform called AddClass.cs is:

```
namespace DelegateTest
{
    class AddClass
    {
        public event ShowMessage OnShowMessage;
        public void AddMe(int a, int b)
        {
            Form1.AnswerEventArgs e = new Form1.AnswerEventArgs();
            e.answer = (a+b).ToString();
            OnShowMessage(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me with the formatting of the code Jon. I struggle with that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is sound except for two details.

First, a `NullPointerException` will occur if your event is raised before any handlers are added.  You can get around this in one of two ways.

1) Make a local copy (to avoid race condition) and check it for null:

```
var showMessage = OnShowMessage;
if (showMessage != null)
{
    showMessage(this, e);
}
```

2) Initialize your event to an empty delegate:

```
public event ShowMessage OnShowMessage = delegate { };
```

---

Second, you do not need to declare your own delegate in this case.  You can simply create a standard `EventHandler` with your own event args:

```
public event EventHandler<Form1.AnswerEventArgs> OnShowMessage = delegate { };
```

---

See [How to: Publish Events that Conform to .NET Framework Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x.aspx) for more information.

Comment: So I replaced the Public event ShowMessage with the public event EventHandler<....   So, now I get: Cannot implicitly convert type 'DelegateTest.ShowMessage' to 'System.EventHandler<DelegateTest.Form1.AnswerEventArgs>'

Comment: Did you remember to change `a.OnShowMessage += new ShowMessage(a_OnShowMessage);` to `a.OnShowMessage += a_OnShowMessage;`?  If that works, you can also delete declaration of `ShowMessage`.

Comment: Ok, I guess it helps to really understand this.  I was poking around there, but thought I would have to pass parameters somehow.  That works great, thank you.

Comment: Having an "initializer" saying `= delegate { }` on a field-like event, I regard as a hack. The recommended way to raise the event is to copy the underlying handler to a local variable, then check that for null. That avoids the race condition you mention. So: `var handler = OnShowMessage; /* gets a local copy of the underlying delegate instance */ if (handler != null) { handler(this, e); }`. See the page you link yourself, the example method `OnRaiseCustomEvent`.

Comment: I edited my answer to make a local copy.  I still prefer the simplicity of `= delegate { }`, hack or not.